# Redirect JSF erro

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, spring

To tentando passar dois parâmetros para outra página exemplo:

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="form?faces-redirect=true&id=cargo.id"></p:commandButton>
```

Mas me retorna esse erro :

```
A referência à entidade "id" deve terminar com o delimitador ';'.
```

Answer (score 2):

É porque você não esta mandando o id corretamento, tem que usar `#{cargo.id}`.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="form?faces-redirect=true&id=#{cargo.id}"></p:commandButton>
```

Assim ele pegar o id corretamente.

Comment: Ele diz que a expressão não é válida

Comment: esse botão esta dentro de uma dataTable?

Answer (score -1):

Troca o `&` por `&amp;`. Olha esse a resposta do link a seguir:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483807/the-reference-to-entity-foo-must-end-with-the-delimiter

"The ampersand `&` is a special character in HTML and XML. If you want to use it as a normal character, you have to encode it correctly. **Write** `&amp;` **instead** of `&`:

```
src="...9623&amp;w=180&amp;h=46&amp;style=white&amp;variant=text&amp;loc=en_US"
```

`&` denotes the start of an encoded entity, such as `&lt;` for `<`, or `&amp;` for `&`. In your case the parser tries to interpret `&w` as an entity. But entities are always terminated by an `;`, thus if the `;` is missing you get the error message."

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/166668)

Comment: Adicionado comentário com as partes essenciais da resposta.